# Swiper Js : how to pass arguments on event

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, swiper.js

I'm trying to pass arguments in my event using swiper,
the docs says:

| Name | Arguments | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lazyImageReady | (swiper, slideEl, imageEl) | Event will be fired when lazy loading image will be loaded |

In my code I have :

```js
swiper.on("lazyImageReady", function () {
    console.log("loaded");
    swiper.params.autoplay.delay = 1500;
    console.log(swiper.params.autoplay.delay);
  });
```

In fact, I would like to fire this event not when all the images are ready, **but only when the first one is.**
I guess that I can specify slide number 1 in the arguments.